# How to write data to a map which field name contains a dot

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the following code

```
admin.firestore().collection("projects")
.doc(projectId)
.update({[`members.${email}`]: "member"});
```

the value of the variable `email` is = `"email@gmail.com"`

**and the result is**

```
{
  members: {
    email@gmail: {
     com: "member"
    }
  }
}
```

**expected result is**

```
{
  members: {
    email@gmail.com: "member"
  }
}
```

I can use **FiealPath** in android(Kotlin) but how to use it in cloud functions (JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to think as JSON keys for the key values. You cannot use dots or special characters that JSON does not support for keys. You could create a parser to change dots for other characters in order to store them in Firebase and then parse them again in the apps.

Answer (score 0):

to update nested objects in typescript you can use

```
admin.firestore().collection('projects').doc('projectid')
.update(members: {
[`${email@gmail.com}`]: "member"
})
```